# Deferred error when jedi:complete-on-dot

Tags: emacs, emacs-jedi

I get the following error when I try to use jedi:complete-on-dot:

`deferred error : (error "Keyword argument :triggered not one of (:requires :force-init)")`

I will note that Jedi is not the only issue I'm having with emacs python modes today. isort stopped working (I fixed this). `M-x python` also stopped working; it simply offers auto-complete suggestions instead of launching a shell (cannot fix this).

Things were working just fine on Monday. Today, they are not working. St

To fix this, I tried updating all of my packages in MELPA, but the issue persists. I'm running emacs 24.5. This was suggested

I realized that, for whatever reason, emacs is pulling Python 2.7, but I actually use Python 3.5. OSX won't let me remove Python 2, because it's used by the OS. To fix py-isort, I just had to install isort via pip outside my virtualenv. I thought the same thing might work for jedi; I installed the following packages again (this time outside my virtualenv):

- jedi
- rope
- epc
- argparse

I also ran `M-x jedi:install-server` and `M-x jedi:setup`. Unfortunately, I still get the error.

One thought I had for fixing this error is to point emacs to python 3.5, but I can't figure out how to do this.

So, again, this issue may not be directly related to jedi, but hopefully someone will be familiar enough with the whole pipeline to help out.

## Additional info

output from `M-x pop-to-epc-buffer` immediately after error:

`56439`

### jedi:show-setup-info

```
;; Emacs Lisp version:
(:emacs-version "24.5.1" :jedi-version "0.2.7" :python-environment-version "0.0.2alpha0")
;; Python version:
((:version "2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]" :name "sys" :file nil)
 (:version "0.9.0" :name "jedi" :file "/Users/alexhall/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jedi/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.5" :name "epc" :file "/Users/alexhall/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/epc/__init__.pyc")
 (:version "0.0.3" :name "sexpdata" :file "/Users/alexhall/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sexpdata.pyc"))
;; Command line:
(:virtualenv "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv" :virtualenv-version "15.0.3\n")
;; Customization:
((jedi:complete-on-dot . t)
 (jedi:doc-display-buffer . display-buffer)
 (jedi:doc-hook view-mode)
 (jedi:doc-mode . rst-mode)
 (jedi:environment-root)
 (jedi:environment-virtualenv)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-delay . 1000)
 (jedi:get-in-function-call-timeout . 3000)
 (jedi:goto-definition-config
  (nil nil nil)
  (t nil nil)
  (nil definition nil)
  (t definition nil)
  (nil nil t)
  (t nil t)
  (nil definition t)
  (t definition t))
 (jedi:goto-definition-marker-ring-length . 16)
 (jedi:imenu-create-index-function . jedi:create-nested-imenu-index)
 (jedi:import-python-el-settings . t)
 (jedi:install-imenu)
 (jedi:install-python-jedi-dev-command "pip" "install" "--upgrade" "git+https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git@dev#egg=jedi")
 (jedi:key-complete .
                    [C-tab])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition .
                           [67108910])
 (jedi:key-goto-definition-pop-marker .
                                      [67108908])
 (jedi:key-related-names . "r")
 (jedi:key-show-doc . "d")
 (jedi:server-args)
 (jedi:server-command "/Users/alexhall/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver")
 (jedi:setup-keys)
 (jedi:tooltip-method pos-tip popup)
 (jedi:use-shortcuts)
 (python-environment-default-root-name . "default")
 (python-environment-directory . "~/.emacs.d/.python-environments")
 (python-environment-virtualenv "virtualenv" "--system-site-packages" "--quiet"))
```

### My init.el

(only the subsection that I think is relevant)

```
;;Set up autocomplete

;;Autocomplete Config
  (require 'auto-complete)
 (require 'auto-complete-config)
 (ac-config-default)
 (global-auto-complete-mode t)

 ;;Add autocomplete for coding
 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/")

 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/auto-complete-1.3.1")

 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-dict")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-clang")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-anaconda")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-helm")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-html")


 ;;Python Mode
;;(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)
 (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)
(defun my-python-mode-hook () 
  (rainbow-mode 1)
  (anaconda-mode 1)
  )

(elpy-enable)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)


(require 'py-isort)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'py-isort-before-save)

;;iPython Notebook
 (autoload 'ein "ein")
(require 'python-django) 
;; enable autopep8 formatting on save
(require 'py-autopep8)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)
```

### The entirety of my messy init.el file (for completeness)

```
;-------;
; REPO  ;
;-------;
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

;make sure the packages are installed; if not install them
(mapc
 (lambda (package)
   (or (package-installed-p package)
       (package-install package)
   )
   )
 '

; generated by C-h v package-activated-list
(ac-anaconda dash anaconda-mode f dash s s dash pythonic f dash s s dash auto-complete popup ac-clang yasnippet pos-tip auto-complete popup ac-helm popup auto-complete popup helm helm-core async popup async ac-html dash f dash s s auto-complete popup ample-theme ample-zen-theme anaconda-mode f dash s s dash pythonic f dash s s dash auctex auto-complete-clang auto-complete popup autopair better-defaults color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow cuda-mode darkburn-theme ecb ein cl-generic request websocket elpy yasnippet pyvenv highlight-indentation find-file-in-project ivy company ergoemacs-mode undo-tree ergoemacs-status mode-icons powerline es-lib exec-path-from-shell find-file-in-project ivy flatland-black-theme flatland-theme flycheck seq let-alist pkg-info epl dash helm-descbinds helm helm-core async popup async highlight-indentation ivy jedi-direx direx jedi auto-complete popup jedi-core python-environment deferred epc ctable concurrent deferred json-rpc let-alist magit magit-popup dash async git-commit with-editor dash async dash with-editor dash async dash async magit-popup dash async markdown-mode+ markdown-mode markdown-mode matlab-mode mode-icons org php-mode pkg-info epl popup-complete popup pos-tip powerline pretty-lambdada py-autopep8 py-isort pydoc pydoc-info python-django python-environment deferred pythonic f dash s s dash pyvenv rainbow-mode request s scss-mode seq smex tidy undo-tree websocket with-editor dash async yasnippet zen-and-art-theme)
)


(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Sets the exec-path to the same value used by the user shell"
  (let ((path-from-shell
         (replace-regexp-in-string
          "[[:space:]\n]*$" ""
          (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -l -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

;; call function now
(set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH)

;; Enable line numbers in all files. 
 (global-linum-mode 1)

 ;; Enable IDO Mode
 ;; Increases Interactivity and ease of use
 ;; e.g. Autocomplete
 (ido-mode 1)
 (setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
 (setq ido-everywhere t)

 ;; Hide splash screen & banner
 (setq inhibit-startup-message t
  inhibit-startup-echo-area-message t)  

 ;; Enable auto-indenting
 (define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)

 ;; Add new lines if using C-n at the end of the buffer
 (setq next-line-add-newlines t)

 ;; Use Zenburn Theme
 ;; Theme must be stored in "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/themes"
 ;; Theme available @ wikemacs.org/wiki/Zenburn-theme
 (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'zenburn t)

 ;; Add Solarized Theme
 (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/themes/emacs-color-theme-solarized")


 ;; Start with subword mode on
 ;; easier navigation of camelCase
 (load "subword.el")
 (global-subword-mode 1)

 ;; Turn on Visible Mark
 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/")
 (load "visible-mark.el")

;; Load extra help commands
 (load "help-fns+.el")

 ;; Turn on Whitespace Mode
 (require 'whitespace)
 (setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail))
(global-whitespace-mode t)
(setq whitespace-global-modes '(c-mode c++-mode cuda-mode web-mode python-mode php-mode))

 ;; Enable Smart Scan Mode
 ;; Quickly search for identifier at current point
 (load "smartscan.el")
 (smartscan-mode 1)


 ;;Store all backup files in C:/Temp
 (setq backup-directory-alist
   `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
 (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
   `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
(put 'set-goal-column 'disabled nil)

;;Swap Windows & Frames quickly
(setq windmove-wrap-around t)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s M-f") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s M-s") 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s M-r") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s M-t") 'windmove-right)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s M-c") 'other-frame)

(global-set-key (kbd "<Shift-up>") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "<Shift-down>") 'windmove-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "<Shift-left>") 'windmove-left)
(global-set-key (kbd "<Shift-right>") 'windmove-right)





 ;;Set up Web-Mode for syntax highlighting

 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/syntax-modes/")
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[gj]sp\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.vtl\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode));; Set PHP-Mode for php files.

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cu$" . cuda-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.upc$" . c++-mode))



(add-hook 'web-hook 'my-web-mode-hook)

(setq-default rainbow-mode 1)
(setq django-indent-width 4)

 ;;Display tabs as 4 spaces.
 (setq-default tab-width 4)
    (defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
    (defvaralias 'cperl-indent-level 'tab-width)

 ;;Next line moves to next ACTUAL line
 ;;ignores word wrap
 (setq line-move-visual 'nil)

 (define-key minibuffer-local-map "\M-s" nil)


(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-names-vector ["#3F3F3F" "#CC9393" "#7F9F7F" "#F0DFAF" "#8CD0D3" "#DC8CC3" "#93E0E3" "#DCDCCC"])
 '(ansi-term-color-vector [unspecified "#393939" "#f2777a" "#99cc99" "#ffcc66" "#6699cc" "#cc99cc" "#6699cc" "#e8e6df"])
 '(background-color "#002b36")
 '(background-mode dark)
 '(cursor-color "#839496")
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("769bb56fb9fd7e73459dcdbbfbae1f13e734cdde3cf82f06a067439568cdaa95" "06f0b439b62164c6f8f84fdda32b62fb50b6d00e8b01c2208e55543a6337433a" "4eaad15465961fd26ef9eef3bee2f630a71d8a4b5b0a588dc851135302f69b16" "2b5aa66b7d5be41b18cc67f3286ae664134b95ccc4a86c9339c886dfd736132d" "ed81411169b1b3e3d4cfc39b09d68ea13e0ff7708dc5b9d0bedb319e071968ad" "51bea7765ddaee2aac2983fac8099ec7d62dff47b708aa3595ad29899e9e9e44" "978ff9496928cc94639cb1084004bf64235c5c7fb0cfbcc38a3871eb95fa88f6" "fc5fcb6f1f1c1bc01305694c59a1a861b008c534cae8d0e48e4d5e81ad718bc6" "17034e7e911c6dced02ff9ed23bae2967b94f2585a7c942afbfae936b9e40a61" "9bac44c2b4dfbb723906b8c491ec06801feb57aa60448d047dbfdbd1a8650897" "e53cc4144192bb4e4ed10a3fa3e7442cae4c3d231df8822f6c02f1220a0d259a" default)))
 '(fci-rule-color "#383838")
 '(foreground-color "#839496")
 '(vc-annotate-background "#2B2B2B")
 '(vc-annotate-color-map (quote ((20 . "#BC8383") (40 . "#CC9393") (60 . "#DFAF8F") (80 . "#D0BF8F") (100 . "#E0CF9F") (120 . "#F0DFAF") (140 . "#5F7F5F") (160 . "#7F9F7F") (180 . "#8FB28F") (200 . "#9FC59F") (220 . "#AFD8AF") (240 . "#BFEBBF") (260 . "#93E0E3") (280 . "#6CA0A3") (300 . "#7CB8BB") (320 . "#8CD0D3") (340 . "#94BFF3") (360 . "#DC8CC3"))))
 '(vc-annotate-very-old-color "#DC8CC3"))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )


;;SET UP ORG MODE
 (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))

 ;;Define Default Workflow States
 (setq org-todo-keywords
       '((sequence "TODO" "NOW" "DONE")))

;; set key for agenda

(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)

(setq org-log-done t)

;;file to save todo items
(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/org/todo.org" "~/Documents/filmGrammar/todo.org")))

;;set priority range from A to C with default A
(setq org-highest-priority ?A)
(setq org-lowest-priority ?C)
(setq org-default-priority ?A)

;;set colours for priorities
(setq org-priority-faces '((?A . (:foreground "#F0DFAF" :weight bold))
                           (?B . (:foreground "LightSteelBlue"))
                           (?C . (:foreground "OliveDrab"))))

;;open agenda in current window
(setq org-agenda-window-setup (quote current-window))

;;capture todo items using C-c c t
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/todo.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO [#B] %? :%^{Tags}:\n:Created: %U\n"  ; template
         :prepend t        ; properties
         :empty-lines 1    ; properties
         :created t        ; properties
         )
        ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/org/journal.org")
         "* %?"
         :empty-lines 1)
        ("n" "Note" entry (file+headline "~/org/notes.org" "Notes")
         "* %?\nEntered on %U\n  %i\n  %a")
        ("f" "filmgrammar todo" entry (file+headline "~/Documents/filmGrammar/todo.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO [#B] %? :%^{Tags}:filmgrammar:ucb:research:code:work:\n:Created: %U\n"  ; template
         :prepend t        ; properties
         :empty-lines 1    ; properties
         :created t        ; properties
         )
        ))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (org-indent-mode t))
          t)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (visual-line-mode -1)
            (toggle-truncate-lines 1)))

;;Mac key rebinds
  (setq mac-option-modifier 'control)
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
  (setq mac-control-modifier 'super)

;;Set up autocomplete

;;Autocomplete Config
  (require 'auto-complete)
 (require 'auto-complete-config)
 (ac-config-default)
 (global-auto-complete-mode t)

 ;;Add autocomplete for coding
 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/")

 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/auto-complete-1.3.1")

 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-dict")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-clang")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-anaconda")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-helm")
 (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/emacsBackup/.emacs.d/general-tools/ac-html")


 ;;Python Mode
;;(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)
 (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)
(defun my-python-mode-hook () 
  (rainbow-mode 1)
  (anaconda-mode 1)
  )

(elpy-enable)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)


(require 'py-isort)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'py-isort-before-save)

;;iPython Notebook
 (autoload 'ein "ein")
(require 'python-django) 
;; enable autopep8 formatting on save
(require 'py-autopep8)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)



(require 'cc-mode)


;; AucTeX
  (setq TeX-auto-save t)
  (setq TeX-parse-self t)
  (setq-default TeX-master nil)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
  (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
  (setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

  ;; Use Skim as viewer, enable source <-> PDF sync
  ;; make latexmk available via C-c C-c
  ;; Note: SyncTeX is setup via ~/emacsBackup/.latexmkrc (see below)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (push
      '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
        :help "Run latexmk on file")
      TeX-command-list)))
  (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))

  ;; use Skim as default pdf viewer
  ;; Skim's displayline is used for forward search (from .tex to .pdf)
  ;; option -b highlights the current line; option -g opens Skim in the background  
  (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
  (setq TeX-view-program-list
       '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b")))



 ;;Markdown Mode
    (autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode"
       "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . markdown-mode))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode))

;; display “lambda” as “λ”
 (global-prettify-symbols-mode 1)
(electric-pair-mode +1)

(setq electric-pair-pairs '(
                            (?\" . ?\")
                            (?\{ . ?\})
                            ) )

(add-hook
   'web-mode-hook
   '(lambda ()
      (setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing nil)
      (setq-local
       electric-pair-pairs
       (append electric-pair-pairs '((?% . ?%))))))





;;tell tramp to use ssh
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")

;;Activate up and down transposing
(defun move-line-up ()
  (interactive)
  (transpose-lines 1)
  (forward-line -2))

(defun move-line-down ()
  (interactive)
  (forward-line 1)
  (transpose-lines 1)
  (forward-line -1)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "<M-down>") 'move-line-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-up>") 'move-line-up)



;; Force frame to 80 column width

(defun set-window-width (n)
  "Set the selected window's width."
  (adjust-window-trailing-edge (selected-window) (- n (window-width)) t))

(defun set-80-columns ()
  "Set the selected window to 80 columns."
  (interactive)
  (set-window-width 80))

(global-set-key "\C-x~" 'set-80-columns)



(setq debug-on-error t)




;; Adapted From Better Defaults.el
(unless (fboundp 'helm-mode)
    (ido-mode t)
    (setq ido-enable-flex-matching t))

  (menu-bar-mode -1)
  (when (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode)
    (tool-bar-mode -1))
  (when (fboundp 'scroll-bar-mode)
    (scroll-bar-mode -1))
  (when (fboundp 'horizontal-scroll-bar-mode)
    (horizontal-scroll-bar-mode -1))

  (autoload 'zap-up-to-char "misc"
    "Kill up to, but not including ARGth occurrence of CHAR." t)

  (require 'uniquify)
  (setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'forward)

  (require 'saveplace)
  (setq-default save-place t)

  (global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'zap-up-to-char)

  (global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-forward-regexp)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-r") 'isearch-backward-regexp)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-M-s") 'isearch-forward)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'isearch-backward)

  (show-paren-mode 1)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t
        x-select-enable-primary t
        save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t
        apropos-do-all t
        mouse-yank-at-point t
        require-final-newline t
        visible-bell nil
        load-prefer-newer t
        ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain
        save-place-file (concat user-emacs-directory "places")
        backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,(concat user-emacs-directory
                                                 "backups"))))

;;; better-defaults.el ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

It version missmatch between emacs jedi package and JEDI library.

For jedi-version "0.2.8" it require:

`pip install jedi==0.17.2`